Kubernetes error unknown field "spec.template.metadata.spec"
I tried to create a file but ends up with an error saying "Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "deployment-definition.yml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.metadata.spec" ". Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: myapp-deployment
 labels:
     app: myapp
     type: front-end

spec:
  template:
    metadata:
     name: myapp-pod
     labels:
        app: myapp
        type: front-end

     spec:
       containers:
       - name: nginx-container
         image: nginx
    
  replicas: 3
  selector:
     matchLabels:
        type: front-end


remove space for spec: block, must be at the same level of metadata:

Your spec.template.spec section is indented under the spec.template.metadata section. spec.template.spec should be on the same indentation level as metadata.
# wrong!
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
     name: myapp-pod
     labels:
        app: myapp
        type: front-end

     spec: # <-- needs to be on the same indentation level as metadata above
       containers:
       - name: nginx-container
         image: nginx

If you are still getting the exact same error, spec.template.metadata.spec then:

double check you are applying the correct file with the updated change. E.g. ensure you saved the file with the updated fix
if you are using other tools that may patch new values into your yaml file before deploying, ensure those aren't causing the issue. E.g. patching the old error version of the file into your new file

Other than that, we would probably need more information to help troubleshoot more.

There is a problem with your yaml format, I have fixed it
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: myapp-deployment
 labels:
     app: myapp
     type: front-end

spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: myapp-pod
      labels:
        app: myapp
        type: front-end
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        image: nginx
  replicas: 3
  selector:
     matchLabels:
        type: front-end


I tried these changes but still says "Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "deployment-definition.yml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.metadata.spec""
